# Community user person account owner changes to random salesforce user

Tags: person-accounts

I am creating a new community user by logging into the community portal which creates a person account in Salesforce, however the account owner is randomly changing to Salesforce user or specific profile.

We have a profile called Licensing Team Member and every time I do a self register and create a new account the person account owner is changed to someone who is a user in this profile.

Can someone help me understand why would this happen?